# IBM MobileFirst - How to set default values for the App Center client app?

Tags: android, client, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776114/ibm-worklight-how-to-set-default-values-for-the-app-center-client-app/28065494?noredirect=1#comment44512300_28065494) and I am having an issue with setting default values. I can get the client to connect but the default values aren't working. In the client without default values I use the the ip:host/applicationcenter to connect. I have tried the same for the default values

"url": "x.x.x.x:9080/applicationcenter",
"defaultPort": "9080",
"defaultContext": "null",

and I tried with and without port and context, tried adding http://x.x.x.x:9080/applicationcenter and still cant figure out why I can't connect. So I am importing the project to my local pc to see if logcat can help. Thought I'd ask here to see if anyone knows what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Comment: What does logcat shows?

Comment: It seems to have been an issue with the mobilefirst version. Pulled the client app from the server and recompiled it locally and it worked with no modifications. So trying to figure out where the mismatch is. I'll post back once I track down why.  I have the same version of mobilefirst running locally on and on a server: 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357. Could there be a mismatch with the appcenter? I did notice the version I compiled locally uses the old appcenter client icon, where as on the server it used a new icon, could that be a clue?

Comment: Might have been a bug with the version you used and the server version; can you write the above as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the `url` property is set, the `defaultPort` and `defaultContext` properties are no longer being used.

BTW, `null` should not be used a string.
The correct used would be:
 `"url": "x.x.x.x:9080/applicationcenter", "defaultPort": null, "defaultContext": null`

And since you did not specify the protocol in the URL, HTTP is used by default.

It could be that by using a newer build you have then used the correct settings needed to connect...

One way to debug it would be to to set the "log" property to true, in order to trace what happens.
You should then see in the Android LogCat for example a string like this:

```
[Appcenter][CordovaPlugin][INFO]: Query login demo on http://localhost:8080/applicationcenter
```

So you can check for the login and URL that are actually being used.

Comment: Thank you Adan, Will see if logcat turns up anything